# How to display all the months between given two dates?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to generate list of months between two dates.
For Example:

```
startDate = '2016-1-31'
endDate = '2017-3-26'
```

It should result as:

```
datetime.date(2016, 1, 31)
datetime.date(2016, 2, 28)
and so on....
```

I am trying like this

```
startDate = '2016-1-28'
endDate = '2017-3-26'

start = date(*map(int, startDate.split('-')))
end = date(*map(int, endDate.split('-')))

week = start
dateData = []

while week <= end:
    dateData.append(week)
    week = week + datetime.timedelta(weeks=4)

pprint(dateData)
```

This gives result as:

```
[datetime.date(2016, 1, 31),
 datetime.date(2016, 2, 28),
 datetime.date(2016, 3, 27),
 datetime.date(2016, 4, 24),
 datetime.date(2016, 5, 22),
 datetime.date(2016, 6, 19),
 datetime.date(2016, 7, 17),
 datetime.date(2016, 8, 14),
 datetime.date(2016, 9, 11),
 datetime.date(2016, 10, 9),
 datetime.date(2016, 11, 6),
 datetime.date(2016, 12, 4),
 datetime.date(2017, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2017, 1, 29),
 datetime.date(2017, 2, 26),
 datetime.date(2017, 3, 26)]
```

Here "2016, 12" & "2017, 1" is repeating twice. Can anybody help me solve this problem.

Comment: you could try relativedelta from library dateutil, it supports months calculation

Comment: yes I did  from dateutil import relativedelta and used relativedelta(months=1). But this is giving error.

Comment: did you try "from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta" ?

Comment: yes I did like that as well. I get error :AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'relativedelta'

Comment: oh I think you have to install python-dateutil for python3. Try "pip install python-dateutil" first. Hope that works

Comment: yes I already have that installed. anyways thank you. i got the solution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) extension's `relativedelta` method like below -

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

startDate = '2016-1-28'
endDate = '2017-3-26'

cur_date = start = datetime.strptime(startDate, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
end = datetime.strptime(endDate, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

while cur_date < end:
    print(cur_date)
    cur_date += relativedelta(months=1)
```

Following is the output

```
2016-01-28
2016-02-28
2016-03-28
2016-04-28
2016-05-28
2016-06-28
2016-07-28
2016-08-28
2016-09-28
2016-10-28
2016-11-28
2016-12-28
2017-01-28
2017-02-28
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r Your answer is helpful for me in developing a list of the months from January 2017 up until the current month. I was just wondering how you would set a variable of the third line of your `while` loop, `cur_date += relativedelta(months=1)`. Using this variable that I would set it to, I would like to append each month into a list, and was just curious. Thanks!

Comment: @florence-y you can simply create a list outside the loop then add a 4th line in the `while` loop, basically `my_list.append(cur_date)`

Comment: sorry to chime in, but what if I want to include the end date month? From the result, it stopped in February month, but the end date is the month of March. @shad0w_wa1k3r

Comment: @wasp8898 simply change the while condition from `<` to `<=`

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't seem to work @shad0w_wa1k3r, still giving me only till Feb.

Comment: @wasp8898 Oh, I didn't realize you wanted a special case to be handled (since endDate is less than a month away). You can simply do `print(cur_date)` after (outside) the `while` loop block & it should work.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use only pandas in one line:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.date_range('2018-01', '2020-05', freq='M')
```

The output will be:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30',
           '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31',
           '2018-09-30', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-30', '2018-12-31',
           '2019-01-31', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-30',
           '2019-05-31', '2019-06-30', '2019-07-31', '2019-08-31',
           '2019-09-30', '2019-10-31', '2019-11-30', '2019-12-31',
           '2020-01-31', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-31', '2020-04-30'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not privileged enough to comment yet, but your program is doing exactly as it is told. 4 weeks equals 28 days. The difference between 1st Jan and 29th Jan (2017) is 28 days; therefore you are getting the same month twice.

You might want to redefine what you are trying to solve. If however, you do want to solve just for the months of the years between the two dates, your code will need some expanding.

1. You need to create a loop to iterate over the years and months.
2. You will need a condition for the start year and end year to ensure you begin at the start month and finish at the end month.

Here is a working example, it includes the start and end dates in the list as well. I hope it helps:

```
import datetime

startDate = '2016-1-28'
endDate = '2017-3-26'

start = datetime.date(*map(int, startDate.split('-')))
end = datetime.date(*map(int, endDate.split('-')))

week = start
dateData = []

dateData.append(start)

rangeYear = (end.year - start.year)

for i in range(rangeYear + 1):
    if i == 0:
        for j in range(1,13-start.month):
            date = datetime.date(start.year, start.month+j, 1)
            dateData.append(date)
    elif (i > 0) & (i < rangeYear):
        for j in range(1,12):
            date = datetime.date(start.year+i, j, 1)
            dateData.append(date)
    elif i == rangeYear:
        for j in range(1,end.month):
            date = datetime.date(start.year+i, j, 1)
            dateData.append(date)

dateData.append(end)
```

Comment: Glad I could help, @Ashish had a much better answer. I never knew `relativedata` existed! Happy coding :)

Comment: In your code, if i have startDate = '2015-4-26' endDate = '2016-5-21', i am getting error. I need this code only if the difference is 365 days that i forgot to mention in question. sorry for that.

Comment: Good catch, I made an error in the for loop condition for `i==0`. It should read `for j in range(1,13-start.month):` instead of `for j in range(start.month,12):`. I've updated it to reflect the changes.